# Show/hide div on mouse over on Rails partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to add a Settings link inside a partial that show/hide when hovered.

The partial is already showing the ID of each item.

```
.item{:id => dom_id(campaign)}
  .. content here
```

I'm a little confused about how to write a js function that shows/hide the link only when the parent div is hovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your jquery tag and your haml example, if your html looks like:

```
.parent_div
  .item{:id => dom_id(campaign)}
```

Then your jQuery can look like this:

```
$('.parent_div').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find('.item').show();
  }
, function() {
    $(this).find('.item').hide();
  }
);
```

Comment: Considering that many parent_div are shown, each Id should be different of this to work which would make to repeat the code every time?

Answer (score -1):

even you can do it with javascript..

for example,

```
function showDiv() {
document.getElementById('test').style.display = "block";
}
function hideDiv(){
document.getElementById('test').style.display = "hide";
}

<div id='test' onmouseover='showDiv()' onmouseout='hideDiv()'>
content...
</div>
```